# Why is the exception stating "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'f' was corrupted." thrown here?

Tags: c, exception, function-pointers

I have written this code:

```
void f1(void)
{
    sprintf("\nf1.");
}
void f2(void)
{
    sprintf("\nf2.");
}
void f3(void)
{
    sprintf("\nf3.");
}
void f4(void)
{
    sprintf("\nf4.");
}
int main()
{
    // int i;
    void (*f[4])(void);
    f[1]=f1;
    f[2]=f2;
    f[3]=f3;
    f[4]=f4;
    (*f[1])();
    (*f[2])();
    (*f[3])();
    (*f[4])();
    /*for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        (*f[i])();
    }*/
    getch();
}
```

The program compiles, runs, and shows the output

```
f1.
f2.
f3.
f4.
```

but when I press enter, it throws the exception stating "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'f' was corrupted."

Please explain to me the reason for this, and also when to use snprintf and sprintf.
Also, let me know why I cannot use

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    (*f[i])();
}
```

for function pointer. It's throwing an error for this as well.

Comment: Remark: `sprintf` does something ___completely different___ than you might think. You want to use `printf`. See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void (*f[4])(void);
f[4]=f4;
```

Arrays start from 0 in C. Accessing `f[4]` is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your out of bounds array problem, you must have this line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

because you're using the `sprintf` function. If you do this, your compiler should give you an error to say you've called it incorrectly. Your compiler has probably warned you that it's used an implicit declaration. As it stands, it's going ahead and calling the function incorrectly and hoping for the best. This may also be causing a stack problem.